# Understanding node.js asynchronicity - for loop versus nested callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback

I'm new to nodejs and is trying to understand its asynchronous idea. In the following code snippet, I'm trying to get two documents from mongodb database randomly. It works fine, but looks very ugly because of the nested callback functions. If I want to get 100 documents instead of 2, that would be a disaster.

```
app.get('/api/two', function(req, res){
        dataset.count(function(err, count){
                var docs = [];
                var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
                dataset.findOne({'index':rand}, function(err, doc){
                        docs.push(doc);
                        rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
                        dataset.findOne({'index':rand}, function(err, doc1){
                                docs.push(doc1);
                                res.json(docs);
                        });
                });
        });
});
```

So I tried to use for-loop instead, however, the following code just doesn't work, and I guess I misunderstand the asynchronous method idea.

```
app.get('/api/two', function(req, res){
        dataset.count(function(err, count){
                var docs = []
                for(i = 0; i < 2 ; i++){
                        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
                        dataset.findOne({'index':rand}, function(err, doc){
                                docs.push(doc);
                        });
                }
                res.json(docs);
        });
});
```

Can anyone help me with that and explain to me why it doesn't work? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can anyone help me with that and explain to me why it doesn't work?**

**tl;dr** -- The problem is caused by running a loop over an asynchronous function (`dataset.findOne`) that cannot complete before the loop completes.  You need to handle this with a library like `async` (as suggested by the other answer) or by callbacks as in the first code example.

**Looping over an synchronous function**

This *may* sound pedantic, but it's important to understand the differences between looping in a synchronous and asynchronous world.  Consider this synchronous loop:

```
var numbers = [];
for( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ){
 numbers[i] = i*2;
}
console.log("array:",numbers);
```

On my system, this outputs:

```
array: [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 ]
```

This is because the assignment to `numbers[i]` happens before the loop can iterate.  For any synchronous ("blocking") assignment/function, you will get results in this manner.

For illustration, let's try this code:

```
function sleep(time){
    var stop = new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date().getTime() < stop + time) {}
}

for( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ){
    sleep(1000);
}
```

If you get your watch out or throw in some `console.log` messages, you'll see that "sleeps" for 5 seconds.

This is because the `while` loop in `sleep` blocks...it iterates until the `time` milliseconds have passed before returning control back to the for loop.

**Looping over an asynchronous function**

The root of your problem is that `dataset.findOne` is asynchronous...which means it passes control back to the loop *before* the database has returned results.  The `findOne` method takes a callback (the anonymous `function(err, doc)`) that creates a closure.

Describing closures here is beyond the scope of this answer, but if you search this site or use your favorite search engine for "javascript closures" you'll get tons of info.

The bottom line, though, is that the asynchronous call send the query off to the database.  Because the transaction will take some time and it has a callback that can accept the query results, it hands control back to the for-loop.  (Important: this is where node's "event loop" and it's intersection with "asynchronous programming" comes into play.  Node is providing a non-blocking environment by allowing asynchronous behavior like this.)

Let's look at an example of how async issues can trip us up:

```
for( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ){
    setTimeout(
       function(){console.log("I think I is: ", i);} // anonymous callback
       ,1  // wait 1ms before using the callback function
    )
}

console.log("I am done executing.")
```

You'll get output that looks like this:

```
I am done executing.
I think I is:  5
I think I is:  5
I think I is:  5
I think I is:  5
I think I is:  5
```

This is because `setTimeout` gets a function to call...so even though we only said "wait ONE millisecond", that's still longer than it takes for the loop to iterate 5 times and move on to the last `console.log` line.

What happens, then, is that the last line fires *before* the first anonymous callback fires.  When it *does* fire, the loop has finished and `i` is equal to `5`.  So what you see here is that the loop is done, has moved on, even though the anonymous function handed to `setTimeout` still has access to the value of `i`.  (This is "closures" in action...)

If we take this concept and use it to consider your second "broken" code example, we can see why you aren't getting the results you expected.

```
app.get('/api/two', function(req, res){
        dataset.count(function(err, count){
                var docs = []
                for(i = 0; i < 2 ; i++){
                        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);

                        // THIS IS ASYNCHRONOUS.
                        // findOne gets a callback...
                        // hands control back to the for loop...
                        // and later pushes info into the "doc" array...
                        // too late for res.json, at least...

                        dataset.findOne({'index':rand}, function(err, doc){
                                docs.push(doc);
                        });
                }

                // THE LOOP HAS ENDED BEFORE any of the findOne callbacks fire...
                // There's nothing in 'docs' to be sent back to the client.  :(

                res.json(docs);
        });
});
```

The reason `async`, promises and other similar libraries are a good tool is that they help to solve the problem you are facing.  `async` and promises can turn the "callback hell" that is created in this situation into a relatively clean solution...it's easier to read, easier to see where async stuff is happening, and when you need to make edits you don't have to worry about which callback level you are at/editing/etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) module. For example:

```
var async = require('async');

async.times(2, function(n, next) {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
  dataset.findOne({'index':rand}, function(err, doc) {
    next(err, doc);
  });
}, function(err, docs) {
  res.json(docs);
});
```

If you want to get 100 documents, you just need to change `Async.times(2,` to `Async.times(100,`.

Answer (score 1):

The async module as mentioned above is a good solution.  The reason this is happening is because a regular Javascript for loop is synchronous, while your calls to the database are asynchronous.  The for loop does not know that you want to wait until the data is retrieved to go onto the next iteration, so it just keeps going, and finishes faster than the data retrieval.